# Why is this code locking so much?

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, locking, python-multithreading

Recently I wanted to write a simple program that reads data from standard input and feeds it into subprocesses. I already wrote an application like this once and it worked, but this time the performance increase wasn't really satisfactory. After noticing that the CPU is barely used, I ran `python -m profile svfeed2.py` and noticed that this mostly runs the `acquire()` function. At first I suspected GIL, but I think I already made all global variables local and it still doesn't help. Here's the code, with profiler's output at the end:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import time
import locale
import subprocess
import re
import threading
import Queue
import copy

from svfeed_config import PG_SERVICEMATCH_CMD, PG_WAIT_TIMEOUT


INSERT_COLUMNS = ('service', 'product', 'version', 'info', 'cpe', 'os',
                  'hostname', 'devicetype') 


FP_START = "SF-Port110-TCP:V=6.40%I=7%D=1/20%Time=52DD2F2C%" \
           "P=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu%r"

MATCH_PATTERN = ('^MATCHED [^ :]+?:(?P<lineno>\\d+)' +
                 '( \\(FALLBACK: [^ ]+\\))?' +
                 ' svc (?P<service>[^ ]+)' +
                 '( p\\|(?P<product>[^\\|]+)\\|)?' +
                 '( v\\|(?P<version>[^\\|]+)\\|)?' +
                 '( i\\|(?P<info>[^\\|]+)\\|)?' +
                 '( h\\|(?P<hostname>[^\\|]+)\\|)?' +
                 '( o\\|(?P<os>[^\\|]+)\\|)?' +
                 '( d\\|(?P<devicetype>[^\\|]+)\\|)?' +
                 '( (?P<cpe>.*?))?$')


def print_stderr(s):
    sys.stderr.write("%s" % s)
    sys.stderr.flush()


def process_line(match_pattern, p, line):   
    ret = []
    if not (
            line.startswith("FAILED") or
            line.startswith("MATCHED") or   
            line.startswith("SOFT MATCH") or
            line.startswith("WARNING")
            ):
        sys.stderr.write("WARNING: UNEXPECTED LINE: %s\n" % line)

    if p.poll():
        sys.exit("Process died.")
    if line.startswith("MATCHED"):
        result = re.match(match_pattern, line)
        assert(result)
        result_dict = result.groupdict()
        for key in result_dict:
            if result_dict[key] is not None:
                result_dict[key] = repr(result_dict[key])[1:-1]
        ret += [result_dict]
    return ret




def read_response(match_pattern, p):
    ret = []
    # Now, read any remaining matches.
    while True:
        line = p.stdout.readline().rstrip("\r\n")
        #print(line)
        if line == "DONE":
            break
        ret += process_line(match_pattern, p, line)
    return ret


def handle_record(match_pattern, fp_start, fp_reply, fp_md5, probe_type, p):
    fp_reply = fp_reply.replace('\\', '\\x5c')
    fp_reply = fp_reply.replace('=', '\\x')
    fp_reply = fp_reply.replace('"', '\\x22')
    fp = fp_start + '%s(%s,%d,"%s");' % (fp_start, probe_type,
                                         len(fp_reply), fp_reply)
    p.stdin.write(fp)
    p.stdin.write("\n\n")
    p.stdin.flush()
    ret = read_response(match_pattern, p)
    if not ret:
        pass
    else:
        for match in ret:
            pass


def worker(q):
    fp_start = copy.copy(FP_START)
    match_pattern = copy.copy(MATCH_PATTERN)
    timeout = copy.copy(PG_WAIT_TIMEOUT)

    p = subprocess.Popen(PG_SERVICEMATCH_CMD,
                         stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         bufsize=0,
                         shell=True,
                         )
    p.stdout.readline()  # skip the "hello" message

    try:
        while True:
            fingerprint, fingerprint_md5, probe, count = q.get(timeout=timeout)
            try:
                handle_record(match_pattern, fp_start, fingerprint, fingerprint_md5, probe, p)
                pass
            finally:
                q.task_done()
    except Queue.Empty:
        pass
    except IOError: # broken pipe due to CTRL+C
        pass
    finally:
        p.stdin.close()
        p.terminate()


def main():
    q = Queue.Queue(maxsize=40)

    for i in range(20):
        t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(q,))
        t.start()

    for line in sys.stdin:
        fingerprint, fingerprint_md5, probe, count = line.split()
        #print(fingerprint_md5)
        q.put([fingerprint, fingerprint_md5, probe, count])


try:
    main()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print_stderr("Caught a KeyboardInterrupt.\n")
    sys.exit(1)
```

And here's the profiler output:

```
      29623 function calls (29620 primitive calls) in 2.134 CPU seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     4171    1.536    0.000    1.536    0.000 :0(acquire)
       76    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 :0(allocate_lock)
     2173    0.015    0.000    0.015    0.000 :0(append)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(compile)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(dir)
        1    0.001    0.001    2.134    2.134 :0(execfile)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(extend)
      120    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(get)
       22    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(get_ident)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(getattr)
       12    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(getlower)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(hasattr)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(insert)
       19    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(isinstance)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(issubclass)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(items)
2146/2145    0.012    0.000    0.012    0.000 :0(len)
      118    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(match)
        8    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(min)
       28    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(ord)
        5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(range)
     3849    0.074    0.000    0.074    0.000 :0(release)
     1775    0.014    0.000    0.014    0.000 :0(remove)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(setprofile)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(setter)
     2000    0.032    0.000    0.032    0.000 :0(split)
       20    0.009    0.000    0.009    0.000 :0(start_new_thread)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(sysconf)
        1    0.000    0.000    2.134    2.134 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 Queue.py:1(<module>)
     2000    0.095    0.000    1.889    0.001 Queue.py:107(put)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Queue.py:13(Full)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Queue.py:17(Queue)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Queue.py:197(_init)
     2012    0.030    0.000    0.042    0.000 Queue.py:200(_qsize)
     2000    0.022    0.000    0.036    0.000 Queue.py:204(_put)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Queue.py:212(PriorityQueue)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Queue.py:22(__init__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Queue.py:231(LifoQueue)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Queue.py:9(Empty)
        1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 bisect.py:1(<module>)
        1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 collections.py:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 collections.py:19(OrderedDict)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 heapq.py:31(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 keyword.py:11(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 pickle.py:1253(_EmptyClass)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 pickle.py:171(Pickler)
        1    0.001    0.001    0.003    0.003 pickle.py:25(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 pickle.py:58(PickleError)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 pickle.py:62(PicklingError)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 pickle.py:69(UnpicklingError)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 pickle.py:82(_Stop)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 pickle.py:827(Unpickler)
        1    0.000    0.000    2.134    2.134 profile:0(execfile('svfeed2.py'))
        0    0.000             0.000          profile:0(profiler)
      118    0.000    0.000    0.002    0.000 re.py:134(match)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.002    0.001 re.py:188(compile)
      120    0.000    0.000    0.004    0.000 re.py:229(_compile)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_compile.py:184(_compile_charset)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_compile.py:213(_optimize_charset)
       13    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_compile.py:24(_identityfunction)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_compile.py:264(_mk_bitmap)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_compile.py:360(_simple)
        3    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 sre_compile.py:367(_compile_info)
      4/3    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 sre_compile.py:38(_compile)
        6    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 sre_compile.py:480(isstring)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.002    0.001 sre_compile.py:486(_code)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.004    0.001 sre_compile.py:501(compile)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:132(__len__)
        6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:136(__getitem__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:140(__setitem__)
       25    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:144(append)
      5/4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:146(getwidth)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:184(__init__)
       47    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 sre_parse.py:188(__next)
       10    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:201(match)
       41    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 sre_parse.py:207(get)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 sre_parse.py:307(_parse_sub)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 sre_parse.py:385(_parse)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 sre_parse.py:669(parse)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:73(__init__)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:96(__init__)
        1    0.001    0.001    0.004    0.004 subprocess.py:377(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 subprocess.py:391(CalledProcessError)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 subprocess.py:402(TimeoutExpired)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 subprocess.py:579(Popen)
        1    0.149    0.149    2.122    2.122 svfeed2.py:121(main)
        1    0.002    0.002    2.133    2.133 svfeed2.py:3(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 svfeed_config.py:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.004    0.004 threading.py:1(<module>)
       45    0.000    0.000    0.003    0.000 threading.py:176(Condition)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 threading.py:179(_Condition)
       45    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 threading.py:181(__init__)
       32    0.001    0.000    0.002    0.000 threading.py:215(_release_save)
       32    0.000    0.000    0.002    0.000 threading.py:218(_acquire_restore)
     2033    0.031    0.000    0.126    0.000 threading.py:221(_is_owned)
       32    0.005    0.000    0.048    0.001 threading.py:230(wait)
     2001    0.074    0.000    0.237    0.000 threading.py:272(notify)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 threading.py:290(notifyAll)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 threading.py:299(_Semaphore)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 threading.py:347(_BoundedSemaphore)
       21    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 threading.py:359(Event)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 threading.py:362(_Event)
       21    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 threading.py:366(__init__)
       20    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 threading.py:371(isSet)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 threading.py:376(set)
       20    0.000    0.000    0.031    0.002 threading.py:391(wait)
       20    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 threading.py:401(_newname)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 threading.py:414(Thread)
       21    0.002    0.000    0.008    0.000 threading.py:426(__init__)
       20    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 threading.py:446(_set_daemon)
       20    0.001    0.000    0.044    0.002 threading.py:463(start)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 threading.py:510(_set_ident)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 threading.py:57(_Verbose)
       87    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 threading.py:59(__init__)
     2053    0.014    0.000    0.014    0.000 threading.py:64(_note)
       20    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 threading.py:683(daemon)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 threading.py:713(_Timer)
        1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 threading.py:742(_MainThread)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 threading.py:744(__init__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 threading.py:752(_set_daemon)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 threading.py:783(_DummyThread)
       20    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 threading.py:808(currentThread)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 threading.py:99(_RLock)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 traceback.py:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.002    0.002 warnings.py:45(filterwarnings)
```

Any ideas what's causing the `acquire()` to kick in so often?

Comment: You could possibly increase the number of tuples passed in a single queue element, so that e.g. each `q.get()` returns a list of 5 tuples `(fingerprint, fingerprint_md5, probe, count)` so that less time is spent on waiting for data, and more on chewing it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to the queue

```
q = Queue.Queue(maxsize=40)
```

looking at the implementation, the queue uses a lock. Maybe you can circumvent this  with another datastructure: A list for every worker used as a queue with `append` and `pop(0)`.

Comment: I have problems imagining the list implementation that would be more efficient than Python's Queue. And about the Queue size, I experimented with making it larger and it didn't really help.